# Protractor Angular 9: browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true); not working

Tags: angular, protractor, webdriver

I am getting very desperate with protractor tests on my Angular 9 app.
using default: `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);` the test are not running at all, the page loads but nothing happens.

With `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` the tests runs but are not reliable making them completely useless. So they might run 5 times well and the sixth time the behaves different. Or they run well on win and on linux bad, or well in firefox but unreliable in chrome.

How can I make my Angular 9 app work correctly with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);`?
What am I missing here. Or is this made for angular1/angularjs ?

Do I neet to run all promises chained like `isPresent().then().then()` or not?

What is the desired way of extracting tests into a function with return value. Does this need to be a function returning a Promise value?

Comment: Those are a lot of questions you have there. Anyways, it seems like you have some `setInterval` or looping `setTimeout` in your application. This will cause protractor to fail, because angular will never be in a 'stable' state. You should run these timers outside of the `ngZone`

Comment: sorry i got them that is right, they exists in code but they are not executed at the page I test. Let's they at the tested login page there is no timeout, but later at the application.

Comment: can you post your code